# Ruby Rake - Running Ruby -w by default?

Tags: command-line, rake, ruby-2.0

When I try and run some basic unit tests on ruby using rake, it appears to turn debugging up on the ruby interpreter. This ends up with me seeing a ton of warning messages in STDOUT. I'm not sure why this is happening and if it should be?

```
D:\dev\git_repos\app_folder>ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p647 (2015-08-18) [i386-mingw32]

D:\dev\git_repos\app_folder>rake test TEST=test/midrange_portal_test.rb
```

like 4 pages of warnings

output which leads me to believe debugging is turned up:

```
Command failed with status (2): [ruby -w -I"lib;test" -
I"D:/apps/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib" 
"D:/apps/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/midrange_portal_test.rb" ]

D:\dev\git_repos\app_folder>gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.14.1
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2015-08-18 patchlevel 647) [i386-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: D:/apps/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: D:/apps/Ruby200/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: D:/apps/Ruby200/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:
     - D:/apps/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
     - H:/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
```

Notice how the command is "ruby -w". I don't know why it defaults to this level of debugging? Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm quite stumped.

Answer (score 0):

So after a lot of digging it turns out the version of rake im using runs ruby with the -w flag by default. If you look in /gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/testtask.rb there is a boolean which sets the ruby warning flag:

```
def initialize(name=:test)
  @name = name
  @libs = ["lib"]
  @pattern = nil
  @options = nil
  @test_files = nil
  @verbose = false
  @warning = true   <--------------------------
  @loader = :rake
  @ruby_opts = []
  @description = "Run tests" + (@name == :test ? "" : " for #{@name}")
  yield self if block_given?
  @pattern = 'test/test*.rb' if @pattern.nil? && @test_files.nil?
  define
end
```

You can monkey patch this to turn it off but in all honesty its probably just a good idea to leave it on and just fix your warnings. In my case I am dealing with a ton of legacy code which is only updated every so often so not really worth it.